# Validation of text_field_tag on click button_tag (without form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I connect the `text_field_tag` with a `button_tag` without a `form_for`?

Here is my code

```
=text_field_tag :test_field, required: true

=button_tag :submit
```

When I press the button—validation (required) is not working.
How do I connect these fields in order to get validation working?

Comment: If you don't wrap the input and submit button in some kind of form I don't think the browser will consider it a valid form and thus the html validations will never trigger (also I don't think the button will go anywhere). Can you post a larger code sample to give more context about what you are trying to accomplish with the input and button?

Comment: You can avoid the form_for helper, but you'll definitely need a form HTML element.